# Cypress file path need to support windows and linux

Tags: linux, cypress

How can we write a file path in cypress tests which support both on `Windows and Linux environments` ? The below is one situation where my test need to copy a `csv` file from one directory to another. Running fine in windows environment, but this is failing in Linux env.

```
fs.createReadStream('C:/Users/Username/Downloads/Export_Survey_CSV.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('C:/somefolder/Project1/Project-Tests/cypress/fixtures/Export_Survey_CSV.csv'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Cypress` support of [environment variables](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html).

For example, have two enviroment variables called `cypress_path_download_folder` and `cypress_path_project_folder` with the respective path to the download's and project's folders on each environment.

Then, you write your tests like this:

```
fs.createReadStream(Cypress.env('path_download_folder') + '/Export_Survey_CSV.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('Cypress.env('path_project_folder')' + '/cypress/fixtures/Export_Survey_CSV.csv'));
```

Comment: Awesome reply ! so if I create a `Cypress.env.json` file and add the following path like below:  `{
  "cypress_path_download_folder": "C:/Users/someusername/Downloads/",
  "cypress_path_project_folder": "C:/somefolder/Project1/Project-Tests/"
 }` and use the above as you suggested, will this work ?

Comment: One more question in my CI/CD env, can I use `relative path` for the project folder `"cypress_path_project_folder": "C:/somefolder/Project1/Project-Tests/"` I might not have the same folder name in CI/CD environment